# box-shadow behaves differently on Safari

Tags: css

I'm trying to create multiple circular shadows on empty `div` using `box-shadow` property and I've got the desired effect on chromium browsers and Firefox, but Safari renders the same code differently - the shadows are more square-looking and colors are less intense in the center of shadow.
Here's a comparison:
[Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkJxD.png) vs
[Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9p3a.png).

I'm basically doing this in css:

```
box-shadow: 20px 20px 40px 32.5px rgb(241, 238, 243),
    20px 20px 55px 50px rgb(218, 44, 204);
```

I made a full reproducible example here: https://jsitor.com/pI7ZoBvTQQ

Does anyone know how to make it look the same in all browsers?

EDIT: Adding `-webkit` prefix doesn't work

Comment: try to add this code : -webkit-appearance: none;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, it looks close enough (still not 1:1 though) to what I was trying to achieve if I add the following properties:

```css
width: 1px;
height: 1px;
border-radius: 50%;
```

Seems like Safari have problems with figuring out the shape of `div` when it's not defined explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 20px 20px 40px 32.5px rgb(241, 238, 243),
    20px 20px 55px 50px rgb(218, 44, 204);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
box-shadow: 20px 20px 40px 32.5px rgb(241, 238, 243),
    20px 20px 55px 50px rgb(218, 44, 204);
-webkit-box-shadow: 20px 20px 40px 32.5px rgb(241, 238, 243),
    20px 20px 55px 50px rgb(218, 44, 204);
```

Comment: Doesn't change anything

Comment: Also can you add this -> ** -webkit-appearance: none;  **

Comment: Still the same.